# Package a game with 64-bit variant

Tags: android, google-play, 64-bit, unreal-engine4

I recently got an email from Google to update my game with a 64-bit variant but, I am out of the game development filed since a few months and quite out of date too, I tried to google it but couldn't find any proper guideline, can anyone help me with this, I have made the game in unreal engine 4.20. If anyone can guide me to the right documentation or suggest me how to do it?

This is the link to my game

[Radiant Runner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HIMCreations.NenonRunner&hl=en)

I know the question is too general, but, I really need help as, I am stuck with something else right now and cannot allocate proper time to this. The game is not popular but it was the first game and only game I made, so wouldn't like it at all if it gets taken down.

Comment: What you need to do is get 64 bit versions of every C library in use by you, either directly or via dependencies.  This may require updating libraries, fixing problems caused by those updates, and/or replacing libraries that don't have 64 bit versions.  Other than that there's nothing we can tell you here.

Comment: Thank you @GabeSechan ,actually, I did the same, I packaged the entire game again in 64-bit, uploaded the arm64-v8a and retained the armeabi-v7a version in my developer's console, so, I think now, I have both 32 and 64 platforms supported.